# Multithreading Python turtle with recursion

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, python-multithreading, turtle-graphics, fractals

I made a Python turtle program that recursively generated a fractal tree, but, since it often took a few hours to fully draw, I wanted to try to use multithreading to have multiple turtles working together.

I was able to get two turtles moving at the same time, but, in this much more complex situation, everything seemed to fall apart. I've tried this many different ways, and thought this final solution would be the one, but it just throws a bunch of errors.

Here's my code:

```
import turtle
import threading
from queue import Queue


class Location:
    def __init__(self, xpos=0, ypos=0, heading=90):
        self.xpos = xpos
        self.ypos = ypos
        self.heading = heading

    def getx(self):
        return self.xpos

    def gety(self):
        return self.ypos

    def geth(self):
        return self.heading


class Turtle(turtle.Turtle):
    def tolocation(self, location):
        self.penup()
        self.setx(location.getx())
        self.sety(location.gety())
        self.setheading(location.geth())
        self.pendown()

    def get_location(self):
        return Location(self.xcor(), self.ycor(), self.heading())

    def draw_tree(self, startpos=Location(), size=100):
        tm.q.put(self.tolocation(startpos))

        for _ in range(size):
            tm.q.put(self.forward(1))
        for _ in range(45):
            tm.q.put(self.right(1))

        t2 = Turtle()
        t2.speed(0)
        tm.new_thread(t2.draw_tree, self.get_location(), size / 2)


        for _ in range(90):
            tm.q.put(self.left(1))
        tm.new_thread(self.draw_tree, self.get_location(), size / 2)


class ThreadManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.q = Queue()
        self.threads = []

    def new_thread(self, func, *args):
        self.threads.append(threading.Thread(target=func, args=(args,)))
        self.threads[-1].daemon = True
        self.threads[-1].start()

    def process_queue(self, scr):
        while not self.q.empty():
            (self.q.get())(1)

        if threading.active_count() > 1:
            scr.ontimer(self.process_queue(scr), 100)


tm = ThreadManager()

scr = turtle.Screen()

t1 = Turtle()
t1.speed(0)
tm.new_thread(t1.draw_tree)

tm.process_queue(scr)

scr.exitonclick()
```

Can anyone give me an idea of where I went wrong here? The error messages say something along the lines of the recursion going too deep when process_queue calls itself. Am I using `scr.ontimer()` wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with your code:

- `draw_tree()` doesn't have a base case to stop it's (conceptual)
  recursion, it just keeps creating new threads.
- Each call to `draw_tree()` divides `size` in half using floating
  division so `range(size)` will fail as `range()` can only take ints.
- Your calls to `self.get_location()` are not valid as it tells you
  where the turtle is, not where it will be once the main thread
  finishes processing outstanding graphics commands.  You have to
  compute where you will be, not look where you are.
- This call, `tm.q.put(self.tolocation(startpos))` isn't valid -- you
  either need to do `tm.q.put(self.tolocation, startpos)` or call
  `tm.q.put()` on each command inside `self.tolocation()`.
- You can't create new turtles anywhere but the main thread, as they
  invoke tkinter on creation and that'll be on the wrong (not main)
  thread.  In my rework below, I simply preallocate them.
- `args=(args,)` is incorrect -- should be `args=args` as `args`
  is already in the correct format.
- You don't need to create two new threads at each branching point, just
  one.  The new turtle goes one way, the old turtle continues on the
  other.

Below is my rework of your code to address the above and other issues:

```
import math
import threading
from queue import Queue
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

class Location:
    def __init__(self, xpos=0, ypos=0, heading=90):
        self.xpos = xpos
        self.ypos = ypos
        self.heading = heading

    def clone(self):
        return Location(self.xpos, self.ypos, self.heading)

class Terrapin(Turtle):
    def tolocation(self, location):
        tm.q.put((self.penup,))
        tm.q.put((self.setx, location.xpos))
        tm.q.put((self.sety, location.ypos))
        tm.q.put((self.setheading, location.heading))
        tm.q.put((self.pendown,))

    def draw_tree(self, startpos, size=100):
        if size < 1:
            return

        self.tolocation(startpos)

        tm.q.put((self.forward, size))

        angle = math.radians(startpos.heading)
        startpos.xpos += size * math.cos(angle)
        startpos.ypos += size * math.sin(angle)

        tm.q.put((self.right, 45))
        startpos.heading -= 45

        tm.new_thread(pond.get().draw_tree, startpos.clone(), size / 2)

        tm.q.put((self.left, 90))
        startpos.heading += 90

        self.draw_tree(startpos, size / 2)

        pond.put(self)  # finished with this turtle, return it to pond

class ThreadManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.q = Queue()
        self.threads = Queue()

    def new_thread(self, method, *arguments):
        thread = threading.Thread(target=method, args=arguments)
        thread.daemon = True
        thread.start()
        self.threads.put(thread)

    def process_queue(self):
        while not self.q.empty():
            command, *arguments = self.q.get()
            command(*arguments)

        if threading.active_count() > 1:
            screen.ontimer(self.process_queue, 100)

screen = Screen()

# Allocate all the turtles we'll need ahead as turtle creation inside
# threads calls into Tk which fails if not running in the main thread
pond = Queue()

for _ in range(100):
    turtle = Terrapin(visible=False)
    turtle.speed('fastest')
    pond.put(turtle)

tm = ThreadManager()

tm.new_thread(pond.get().draw_tree, Location())

tm.process_queue()

screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]

if instead of large steps:

```
tm.q.put((self.right, 45))
```

you want to break down graphic commands into small steps:

```
for _ in range(45):
    tm.q.put((self.right, 1))
```

that's OK, I just wanted to get the code to run.  You need to figure out if this gains you anything.

Comment: Great answer, thank you. Is it possible to make these turtles move at the same time instead of taking turns as they are? I understand that threads cannot actually execute at the same time anyways and instead take turns, but even when I split up the commands into small ones it still moves the turtle all 100 steps of 1 before moving a different turtle.

Comment: @BradenWilson, possibly but this not a good case for threads -- the overhead of multiple threads outweighs any gain.  A suitable problem would require more computation per branch such that the computation outweighs both the thread and graphics overhead.  In this example, by the time you see the drawing start, all the *computation* is over and the program is waiting for the drawing to catch up and finish.